# C++: Copy constructor call using curly braces

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list, brackets, curly-braces

Suppose I have the following piece of code where the only things about `Type` I know are:

1. `Type` does not implement constructor with signature `Type(std::initializer_list<Type>)` i.e. constructor taking an initalizer list consisting of `Type` elements as its argument
2. `Type` does implement default and copy constructors

```
/*
 all necessary includes
*/

 int main()
{
   Type t{};          //calls default c-tor
   Type t_ref(t);     //Reference case. calls copy c-tor

   Type t1{t};        //Case 1. is there any difference from Reference case?
   Type t2 = Type{t}; //Case 2. is there any difference from Reference case?
   Type t3{Type{t}};  //Case 3. is there any difference from Reference case?
   Type t4 = {t};     //Case 4. is there any difference from Reference case?
}
```

I know curly braces are used for initializer lists, but I have not found how they behave by the standard in cases shown in the code above.

1. Can I be 100% sure all four cases behave exactly the same in all possible cases as the Reference case? If not, when and what is the difference?
2. Are there any drawbacks of using curly brackets over simple brackets when copy constructing an object in C++?

Comment: why do you call it "reference case" ? `t_ref` is a `Type` it is not a reference

Comment: oh, I think it get it ;). It is the reference case you use as reference for the other examples

Comment: From C++17 onward [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) impacts quite a few of your test cases _"...First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object..."_ ; see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: What Richard said is very important if you are dealing with C++11 or C++14.  If you have code that is relying on C++11/14 behavior, but then the compiler is upgraded with C++17 or later and then behaves differently — or *vice versa* — it can be a frustrating situation to detangle.

Comment: @Eljay can you be please more specific? What is/can be the differnce in each of given cases (mostly I'm interested in Case 1. )? So should I prefer using simple brackets over curly whenever possible?

Comment: @cerveka2 generally since C++17 it shouldn't matter that much. Before, I'd go with `Type name{arg1, arg2, arg3};` if performance really matters that much. The bigger problem is that `auto mtx = std::mutex{}` might suddenly stop compiling if one switches from C++17 to 14 due to the type lacking copy/move ctors and copy elision not kicking in anymore. See [Sy Brand's blog](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/guaranteed-copy-elision/) for more detailed info :)

Comment: For more information, I recommend CppCon 2018 Nicolai Josuttis [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).  It's an hour long presentation, but thorough.

Comment: For more information, I recommend CppCon 2018 Nicolai Josuttis [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).  It's an hour long presentation, but thorough.

Comment: `a b(c);` can declare variable `b` (calling a ctor with argument `c`) or can declare a function `b` from type `c` to type `a` (see the "most vexing parse"). Instead, `a b{c};` always calls a constructor of type `a` (but watch out for ctors taking `initializer_list`s -- `vector v(5); vector w{5};` differ a lot).

Comment: @chi Yes, I know, that's one of the reasons I'm asking this question. But for that case I explicitly declare the constructor taking initializer list does not exist. So can I be 100% sure the Case 1 is the same as the Reference case?